# Docker container Linux weird behavior when reading Python arguments with *

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker

I have built a linux docker container containing `Python3` (python 3.5) and running a python application (standard docker with Keras, similar to [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/docker)).

All is good. The problem is when I'm trying to run an application reading arguments, it considers the character `*` as multiple arguments! For instance when I do `python3 myapp.py * -1`, it prints `len(sys.argv): 6`, but if I do `python3 myapp.py 1 -1`, it prints the correct number.

```
print("len(sys.argv): "+str(len(sys.argv)))
```

Basically, I wanted to look for all files in a directory and this was the weird behavior. Now I hard-coded `*` inside the code, and it is working now.

Anyone experience this weird behavior before?! Why is this?

Comment: This is the automatic wildcard expansion by the Linux shell. Replacing `*` by `\*` should work.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with Docker? Doesn't it do the same thing from a normal shell?

Comment: This is how commands like `cat *.txt` and `rm *jpg` work. The shell replaces the wildcard with all the matching filenames. Why would it be different for python?

Comment: Because on Windows it works perfectly...hence my surprise.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks. Feel free to add that as an answer to give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux shells (unlike Windows) replace wildcards with a space separated list of files and/or directories before the actually called program sees the parameter(s). You can try this in a Linux shell e.g. with

```
echo *
```

to print all files of the current directory.

To avoid this, the asterisk must be escaped with a backslash. It will then be handed to the program as it is (without the backslash). E.g.

```
echo \*
```

Shows

```
*
```